# encoded strings issues

Tags: android, encoding

I am working on my very first Android application, I am getting some Arabic messages in the JSON response from a web service in two different formats. when I display one of them get translated correctly but other get printed as it is in the encoded message.

Here is the first one:

```
\u0635\u0641\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0638\u0641\u0631
```

This is converted to proper Arabic string as intended.
but

```
&#1705;&#1575;&#1605;&#1585;&#1575;&#1606;
```

does not, I was expecting that its a UTF-8 encoded message, but I'm unable to convert it. can anyone help me to understand this encoded message?

Here is how I tried to convert but its unchanged:

```
public String decodeString(String encodedString) {
  try {
    return new String(encodedString.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
  } catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    return encodedString;
  }
}
```

any help is appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

When I check (`&#1705;&#1575;&#1605;&#1585;&#1575;&#1606;`) message here: http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf8_decode I get the correct response.

Please also share some details on the encoding scheme i-e what is the difference between both encodings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&#1705;&#1575;&#1605;&#1585;&#1575;&#1606;` Looks like the HTML encoding of the Unicode code points. You'll need to decode the HTML, using e.g Apache commons [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml(java.lang.String))().

Here's the gradle dependency for the library:

```
compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
```

Comment: Do you have idea of this format (\u0635) when i tried it on: http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf8_decode  it was unable to understand this. which encoding is this ?